# Clarifying responsibility with named parameters

Tags: python, interface, refactoring

More and more often recently I've wanted to do something like the following:

```
def refund(amount, yes_i_know_i_need_to_handle_credit):
    __refund(amount)

total = 600
card_total = 400
user_credit_refund = total - card_total

# This raises an error
refund(total)

# This works
refund(card_total, True)

user.print_credit += user_credit_refund
```

Pseudocode, obviously, but the issue I want to point out is that the refund function without the second parameter is a leaky abstraction - the user has to look inside it to figure out whether it handles user credit refunds. If they passed the full total to the refund method, they would refund more than the user paid in real money.

The reason I feel like this is useful is to clarify changes that are happening during a refactor. The refund function used to handle refunding user credit, but I'm decoupling the billing stuff from the product manipulation, so the refund function no longer handles print credit - the user of the function has to do that part separately.

I've never seen this design pattern anywhere, though I have seen the like in more strongly typed languages for type checking, etc. And there's no purely programmatic reason for it, since an interface should be well documented and just do what it does. But historically, the behavior of this function has changed, and I want to enforce remembering that.

So what do you all think? Idiocy? Useful? Achieved some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't require an argument which has no purpose other than forcing the user to pass a useless value. (Imagine how annoying that would be a year from now when everyone has updated their code but still forced to kowtow to the gods of a nagging API.)

Changing the API is always painful since it will break user's code, and is bound to cause some confusion.

However, if you are willing to suffer the pain to achieve a better code base, then I would suggest changing the *function name* instead of adding a parameter:

```
def handle_refund_and_credit(total, card_total, user):
    total = 600
    card_total = 400
    user_credit_refund = total - card_total
    handle_refund(total)
    user.print_credit += user_credit_refund

def handle_refund(amount):
    __refund(amount)
```

Since there is no function named `refund`, the user will be force to select the function they need: either `handle_refund_and_credit`, or just `handle_refund`. They'll have to research what each one does, and they'll be guided by the list of required arguments.